# How to change all of text size in java android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

for example if device size is 4 inch i need 12-dot per inch size and if size of the screen is 5 or more need 15-dot per inch size for text and how to change all text size with one method i know how to change size text.
if any idea write it 
thanks in advance.

Comment: I strongly believe setting text size based on physical screen size is a bad idea

Comment: what could i do ? @Shaishav

Comment: What issues are you facing with `sp`?

Comment: i install my application in my device and my father device in my device every things is ok but my father device is 4 inch and every text was too large @Shaishav

Comment: In your layout editor , did you try to check with the "Preview All Screen Sizes" option?

Comment: no what is that? @Shaishav

Comment: yes i checked it @Shaishav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say small, medium and large text appearance and android will manage according to screen sizes.

For small

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
```

Like this for medium and large

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

If this didn't solve your problem. Then you have to give different values for different dimensions.

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) google documentation for managing multiple screen sizes.

Comment: i know that all of my issues is about screen size for text size if i use small text size,text in screen with more than 5 is too small

Comment: Did you try textAppearance?

Comment: Try making different value folders like **values-w320dp-mdpi, values-w360dp-mdpi and so on**

Answer (score 0):

There are resource qualifiers for screen sizes:

```
layout-small
layout-medium
layout-large
layout-xlarge
...
values-small...
```

This should allow you to define different resources based on physical screen sizes. However, I would suggest against it. You can get more information about these [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview).